# Sometimes when I delete my own post, it prevents me from interacting with it until I refresh the page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This is probably not a very big deal, and there might be a duplicate post here somewhere, but anyways...

Most of the time, when I delete my own post, the post just turns red and I am able to un-delete it if I want. But sometimes (rarely), when I delete my own post, it will show a message saying something like "the post was deleted and cannot be displayed" and it won't let me interact with the post until I refresh the page. I guess there is some kind of race condition between the two events and the message that blocks the post gets triggered first.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is more of a result of an AJAX call never completing correctly.

If it does, you get the post in red, if it doesn't, you get the blocking notice.

The blocking notice is a fix to a situation where you delete a post and then... nothing happening - the page didn't turn red, it looked like nothing was deleted.

Comment: Wait, but if the "the post was deleted" message is displayed before the AJAX response comes back, doesn't that mean that that message can be displayed even if the request didn't actually go through? If so, then that seems like a bug; it should instead say something like "the post is being deleted".

Comment: @ruakh - I don't think it works exactly like that.